# Verilog code with wrong waveform (Mutliplier Circuit)

Tags: verilog, quartus

```
module multiplication (multiplier, multiplicand, product, clk);

input [3:0] multiplier;
input [4:0] multiplicand;
input clk;
output [7:0] product;
reg [7:0] product;

initial
begin
    product [7:4] = 4'b0000;
    product [3:0] = 4'b1100;
end

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    if (product[0] == 1)
    begin
        product <= product >> 1;
        product[7:3] <= product[7:3] + multiplicand[4:0];
    end
    else
    begin
        product <= product >> 1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

This verilog code is to implement the circuit mentioned in this question: [How to perform right shifting binary multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002038/how-to-perform-right-shifting-binary-multiplication), the waveform is correct until the last step. The correct answer should be 00111100

Waveform:
[image: Waveform]

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be?

We know at t=300ns, `product[0]==1`, so we're using the first option of the if-else.
In that case, we have the following:

```
    product <= product >> 1;
    product[7:3] <= product[7:3] + multiplicand[4:0];
```

Because you're (correctly) using non-blocking assignments, the value of `product` isn't updated until the always block completes. That means the second assignment uses the unshifted value of product. We could simplify this expression as

```
    product[2:0] <= product [3:1];
    product[7:3] <= product[7:3] + multiplicand[4:0];
```

and the result would be the same.

The first statement give us `0b100`. The second gives us `0b00101 + 0b00101 = 0b01010`. In total, this produces `0b01010100`, which matches the simulation output.

Comment: That may be. My point was that the problem isn't with the simulator, but with your algorithm and/or implementation. The output of the simulator matches the code you've written.

Comment: One fix could be to replace the assignment in the first half of the if-else with `product = {product[7:3] + multiplicand[4:0], product [2:1], 1'b0};`, in order to add a cycle for the addition. (i.e. shift->shift->add->shift->add). You would set bit [0] to 0 to indicate that you've done the addition for that stage.