# Replace right shift by multiplication

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I know that it is possible to use the left shift to implement multiplication by the power of two (`x << 4 = x * 16`).
Also, it is trivial to replace the right shift by division by a power of two (`x >> 5 = x / 32`).

I am wondering is it possible to replace the right shift with multiplication?
It seems to be not possible in the general case, but my question is limited to modulo 2^32 and 2^64 arithmetic (unsigned 32-bit and 64-bit values). Also, maybe it can be done if we can add other cheap instructions like `+` and `-` in addition to `*` to emulate the right bit shift?

I assume exotic architecture where the right shift is more expensive than other arithmetic (similar to division).

```
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x) {
    return x >> 3; // how to avoid using right shift here?
}
```

There is a similar question [How to perform right shifting binary multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002038/how-to-perform-right-shifting-binary-multiplication) that asks how to replace multiplication of two unsigned numbers by right shift. Basically, it uses a loop internally. However, maybe if the second number is a constant, this loop can be avoided (or at least unrolled to a shorter fragment)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You've already acknowledged that shifting right by `n` is equivalent to dividing by `2^n`, so it's equivalent to multiplying by `(1/2)^n`. What is unclear to you?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added a code fragment that should explain it better. Basically, I operate on unsigned numbers and can't represent factors like (1/2) there.

Comment: What's the problem with shifting right if that is what you want to do? I don't understand how this is an issue.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It is expensive (takes a lot of cpu cycles).

Comment: And multiplication will take less? I doubt it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, integer multiplication takes less. I understand your doubt because it is not true for intel x86, but what if we consider such exotic architecture where this is true?

Comment: For example, which architecture? Even if it were the case, you should leave it to the compiler to make such optimizations and use the most appropriate CPU instructions.

Comment: I don't mean any particular widespread architecture. I mean that theoretically, you can design it for solving specific tasks (like ASICs and FPGAs).

Comment: Shifting is a very light operation. I don't think you can find a cheaper one by mixing aritmetic. Also note that some people are suggesting multipling by `float`s  that's just more CPU consuming and you'll mix your types. It is an interesting thought , but I'm pretty sure you won't find anything better than shifting or dividing by 2^n

Comment: Seconding Ivan. People (and optimizing compilers...) **replace** multiplication with left-shifts because shifting is cheaper (by an order of magnitude, and not only on x86). I can't picture any architecture where some "magic" multiplication "plus something else to get it right" can ever beat the right shift performance-wise.

Comment: Multiplying is an operation that includes repeated shifting and addition. E.g. a*1101 is (a<<3 + a<<2 + a). There will be no architecture on which that is faster than a single shift without addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Multiply-high](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28868367/555045)" aka high-mul, hmul, mulh, etc, can be used to emulate a shift-right with a constant count. Usually that's not a good trade. It's also hardly related to C++.

Normal multiplication (putting floating point stuff aside) cannot be used to implement a shift-right.

> my question is limited to modulo 2^32 and 2^64 arithmetic

It doesn't help. You can use that property to "unmultiply" (sort of like divide, except not really) by odd numbers, for example if `b = 5 * a` then `a = b * 0xCCCCCCCD`, using the modular multiplicative inverse. The number being inverted must be relatively-prime relative to the modulus. Since the modulus is a power of two, the "divisor" here cannot be a power of two (except 1, but that does nothing), so a shift-right cannot be done this way.

Another way to look at it (probably simpler), is that what a multiplication does is conditionally add together a bunch of left-shifted versions of the multiplicand. Only left-shift versions, not right-shifted versions. Which of those shifted versions are selected by the multiplier doesn't matter, there are no right-shifted versions to select.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think about using multiply-high. It solves my problem for 32-bit unsigned numbers when 64-bits of multiplication are available.